# Why doesn't support click handler event SVG element in Firefox and Safari and Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, svg

**The web application**

It is a web-based finding map game site built with Angular 4. It has various selection game mode and runs based on the selection mode also many regions that can choose/select or only one region then populate the country name to find each cycle.

**What should be the correct behavior**

*All data populating from SVG document

1. After page load - Options to choose ['New Game', 'Achievement', 'HighScore']
2. Choose a game mode ['learning', 'classic', 'time']
3. Select regions (one or more) then press play to play the game
4. Display the SVG map and name to find a country randomly from SVG
5. Click on a country then if a user clicked correct country notification 'correct' if not notification would be 'incorrect' (there are the logic that can count the correct/incorrect point)
6. Move next Country to find (then repeat step 5)
7. End game
8. It should work all in the major Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, Internet Explorer)

*Game Mode*

- LearningMode = always repeat game
- ClassicMode = run only one time and end
- TimeMode = has a time limit to finish otherwise game over

**Here is a partial code it handles the click event**

```ts
public handleClickEvent(event: any): void {
  if (this.gameStarted && event.path && event.path.length > 0) {
    const country = event.path[0].id;
    if (
      country !== null &&
      country !== 'europeanMap' &&
      country !== 'image97'
    ) {
      this.runGameLogic(country);
    }
  }
}
```

**Game run logic**

```ts
// The user clicked on the map, so run game logic on that

  private runGameLogic(selectedCountryName: string): void {
    const index = this.selectedCountries.findIndex(country => {
      return country.name === this.countryToFind.name;
    });
    this.selectedCountries[index].selected = true;
    // Only run logic if the game has started, there is a valid countryName object, and that object is not equal to an empty string
    if (selectedCountryName && selectedCountryName !== '') {
      if (selectedCountryName === this.countryToFind.name) {
        this.correctAnswerLogic(index);
        this.selectedCountries[index].correct = true;
      } else {
        this.incorrectAnswerLogic(index, selectedCountryName);
      }
    }
  }
```

I need to figure out how I can make cross-browser capabilities app or what could be possible solutions that the browser does support mine app.

Thank you for help **:)**

Comment: Please include a working [mcve] for your question.  What you have provided here is not dufficient to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thank you for comment and asking to provide more in details. I try to summarize my situations in detail, let me know if that's not enough though I will provide more.

Comment: It's still not what we need really. What we want is a minimal runnable example.

Comment: @RobertLongson I guess its very complicated to mine (I'm a beginner with Angular/Programming) put runnable example because built with Angular and Multiple reference file and methods. But I did provide some more related code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the Firefox browser. The reason was Firefox doesn't have `event.path` property and it doesn't triggering the click event though I found this `event.composedPath()` it works with all major browser except Edge/IE more detail in [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath). 
Here is an actual code that works fine on Firefox.

```
public handleClickEvent(event: any): void {
  const path = event.path || event.composedPath();
  if (this.gameStarted && path && path.length > 0) {
    const country = path[0].id;;
    if (
      // some conditions
    ) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

I still need to solve in the Edge/IE browser.
Thanks